# Wahoo KICKR 2018 and Shimano Sora 11-32t 9-speed compatibilty

Tags: trainer

At present, I own [Specialized Allez e5 Sport](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/allez-e5-sport/p/115476) which has the default Shimano Sora cassette (11-32t) and rear derailleur.

I'm planning to buy Wahoo KICKR (for long-term, given more bike(s) will come), so my doubt is that is my current bike even compatible with the trainer, given that Wahoo does provide the 1.8mm spacer.

Comment: Your local bike store or many online stores will have spacers in different sizes available if your cassette that you might want to use doesn't fit. But it will. 8-/ 9- and 10-speed Shimano cassettes require a 1.8mm spacer on an 11-speed hub, whereas the 11-speed fits without. So don't worry about upward compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bike should be compatible per wahoo:
"The KICKR uses an 11-speed compatible Shimano freehub body, but you can install an 8, 9, or 10 speed cassette with the proper spacers."

https://support.wahoofitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/204281874-Difference-between-10-speed-and-11-speed-KICKRs-

You should be fine installing the 1.8mm spacer on the kickr along with a 9-speed Shimano cassette. The same spacer is needed for installing 10-speed Shimano cassettes. Just make sure there is no play in the cassette after installing, if there is, you should be able to get different sized spacers from any bike shop as needed.

Comment: Ok, the trainer will arrive in the next 20 days or so. Will update you, how it fitted.

Comment: I got my Kickr yesterday and it did fit perfectly on my 9 speed SORA cassette with the 1.8mm spacer provided along with it.

Comment: Great @harman786! Good to hear it’s working well!

Comment: "_The same spacer is needed for installing 10-speed Shimano cassettes_" - I think this is not the case. 10-speed cassettes need an *additional* 1mm spacer on Shimano 11-speed freehubs. Sounds counterintuitive, I know. a 9speed cassette on an 11-speed Shimano freehub needs 1.85mm... a 10-speed cassette on *the same freehub* needs 2.85mm (because 10-speed cassettes are 1mm "shallower" than 9-speed).  SlowTwitch covered this in 2013 and I don't think anything has changed since.  -> https://www.slowtwitch.com/Tech/Cassette_Spacers_2013_3978.html - helped me put a 9sp Dura Ace cassette on my KickR.